# How do I combine tables with a conditional sum? SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to combine tables 1 and 2 into table 3.  I need to group the rows from table 1 to match the format of table two while summing c1, c2, and c3 for each range.

My understanding of joins is weak, and help is appreciated.

Table 1:

```
ID     begin    end    c1   c2   c3
78JUE  20       24     1    0    0
78JUE  24       28     2    1    0
78JUE  28       32     1    1    0
78JUE  32       36     0    0    0
78JUE  36       40     0    0    0
78JUE  40       44     4    1    1
78JUE  44       48     3    1    1
78JUE  48       52     1    2    0
78JUE  52       56     0    1    1
78JUE  56       60     2    0    1
78JUE  60       64     1    1    0
78JUE  64       68     0    2    1
```

Table 2:

```
ID     begin  end
78JUE  20     40
78JUE  40     52
78JUE  52     60
78JUE  60     68
```

Table 3:

```
ID     begin  end  c1  c2  c3
78JUE  20     40   4   2   0
78JUE  40     52   8   4   2
78JUE  52     60   2   1   2
78JUE  60     68   1   3   1
```

Comment: What happens with row `51.85 - 55.77`? Does it get counted twice in the range `40-52`, and also in `52-60`?

Comment: @TheImpaler - My assumption is that the ranges are upper-bound exclusive, which is what they should be (for one thing, an inclusive upper bound is difficult to use with more precise value data - we don't know the precision limits)

Comment: The values in columns c1,c2, and c3 are irrespective of the begin-end columns.

Comment: Edit - I rounded the begin-end columns in Table 1

Comment: @SC2018 - er, what?  That's fairly important information for us to know.  For one thing, my default assumption with these types of queries is that only the lower-bound start values should be considered, but doing so yields a different calculation than what you've provided for your sample results.

Comment: begin-end columns are distances. c1,c2,c3 columns are instances between those distances.  Table three is saying there are four instances of c1 between 20 and 40 in table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi, this should do it:

```
SELECT
 T1.ID
,T1.begin
,T1.end
,SELECT(SUM(T2.c1) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.begin >= T1.begin AND T2.end <= T1.end) c1
,SELECT(SUM(T2.c2) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.begin >= T1.begin AND T2.end <= T1.end) c2
,SELECT(SUM(T2.c3) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.begin >= T1.begin AND T2.end <= T1.end) c3
FROM Table1 T1
```